# changing indicator background

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a table with alternating row colors (I used the following expression `=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "Gainsboro", "White")`). Now in one of the table's cell I putted an indicator.

When I run my report, the indicator's background color stay fixed as white:

[image]

I tried to set the indicator background color to `no color`.

I also did some workarounds (created image files with the indicator icons - 2 images per icon (each one with different background color), and used an expression to switch between the images. but this workaround is restrictive (because i have to keep the cell proportions right as the image proportion - otherwise the images presented badly)

**Do you know any option/better workaround to solve this issue ?** thank you.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/feldman/archive/2007/11/18/transparent-images-in-reporting-services.aspx) help? It suggests you wrap the img inside a rectangle, for some reason.

Comment: It gave me some directions - I put rectangle inside a table's cell, and then an indicator inside the rectangle. its working - Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! I'll post it as an answer as well then so others that land on this question may easily spot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

The way to fix it is as follow

**Solution for problem 1:**

Click on the "Row" itself not on one of the columns (See screenshot)

Then add your expression to the "Background Color" Property

```
=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "Gainsboro", "White")
```

[image]

**Solution for problem 2**

The way to force the image not to increase is to set the column property "Can Grow" to False

Please do so to every column (See screenshot) 
I hope it helped you :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/feldman/archive/2007/11/18/transparent-images-in-reporting-services.aspx) may help: it suggests you wrap the img inside a rectangle, apparently transparency in images is then forced to be rendered correctly.

Comment: I marked @silagy as the right answer because his answer doesn't involved with any workarounds. Thank you though for your affort